# What is the difference between @Profile("String") and @ProfileName

Tags: java, spring

What is the difference between these two profiles definition.

```
@Profile("prod")
public DatabaseDatasource getProductionDatabase() {
//code
}
```

and

```
@Profile("prod")
public @interface ProdProfile{}

@ProdProfile
public DatabaseDatasource getProductionDatabase() {
//code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not difference.

The difference is that you only write your desired Profiles as interfaces.
If you ever decide to change the profile name, you only have to change it in a single place instead of searching through an entire project the literal "prod", like in your example.

Either than not repeating yourself, it should work the same